# Resolving "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" and "Mixed Content: ... the content must be served over HTTPS." errors after converting site to HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I first implemented my site on a remote VPS without SSL, but then recently got certs from letsencrypt.org.

The site is now accessible at https://www.example.com but some of my GET requests began throwing "Mixed Content ... the content must be served over HTTPS." errors in the inspection console, so I tried changing the base reference in my JS code from:

http://www.example.com:3000

to

https://www.example.com:3000

and now I'm getting this error: "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Is there more that I need to do to make port 3000 or mongo serve correctly across https?

I'm pretty new to all of this, so any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: the problem is nothing to do with mongo, it's to do with your web code ... you probably have some AJAX that uses `http://....` instead of `https://...` edit: re-reading the question, what do you mean "base reference" ... note: it's really hard to help someone with a bug in their code when there's no code

Comment: I added some more context to my issue in a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434392/mixed-content-and-err-ssl-protocol-error-errors-while-trying-to-use-ssl-http), perhaps you can have another look at it @Jaromanda X, thanks!